# How can I create a dynamic select form using a dictionary in Flask?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, flask, flask-wtforms

**I have a list within a dictionary within a dictionary that is structured like so:**

```py
spotDictionary = {Firm, {Product, [Spot]}}
```

I want to have 3 select fields Firm, Product, Spot. From left to right the user should select one from each. **Each select field should dynamically populate the choices with those that correspond with the Firm or Product.**

In other words, when I select FirmA I should only see FirmA's products. When I select FirmA's corresponding products, I should only get the Spots for that product. Once all 3 select fields are populated, the user may submit the form.

Below is how I created the list of Firms that I use as my first select fields (Firms) choices. I would like to use a similar logic in the select fields that follow. **I do not want to query the database since I already have a spotDictionary.**

```py
firmList = sorted([[i, i] for i in spotDictionary.keys()]
```

**Once a user selects a firm, the next select field's options should be that firms products and that firms products only. This should be the same for the Spot once the user selects a Product.**

Comment: You're not using wtforms here. It's not tough to do, but you aren't using the tech you say you are

Comment: @roganjosh I am intending to use it but want to use it with a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar recently by using multiple forms in the same template with multiple render_template calls. Where each form is submitted on change and populates the next form.

If you dont want to call the db multiple times you could store it in the session variable.

this isnt tested, but something along the lines of:

```
class Firm(FlaskForm):
    firm = SelectField('firm', coerce=str, validators=[InputRequired()])
class Prod(FlaskForm):
    prod = SelectField('prod', coerce=str, validators=[InputRequired()])
class Spot(FlaskForm):
    spot = SelectField('spot', coerce=str, validators=[InputRequired()])

@app.route
def route(): 

    if form1.validate_on_submit():
        form2.prod.choices = session.data.prodlistfunction
        return render_template("/", form1=form1, form2=form2, form3=form3)

    if form2.validate_on_submit():
        form3.spot.choices = session.data.spotlistfunction
        return render_template("/", form1=form1, form2=form2, form3=form3)

    if form3.validate_on_submit():
        do.something()

    data=db.call()
    session.data = data
    form1 = Firm()
    form2 = Prod()
    form3 = Spot()
    form1.choices = data.somefunction()  
    # give other forms blank choices to start off with
    form2.choices = ["",""]
    form3.choices = ["",""]   

    return render_template("/", form1=form1, form2=form2, form3=form3)
```

and then for the template something like

```
<form>
{{ form1.csrf_token }}
{{ form1.firm(onchange='this.form.submit()') }}
</form>
<form>
{{ form2.csrf_token }}
{{ form2.prod(onchange='this.form.submit()') }}
</form>
<form>
{{ form3.csrf_token }}
{{ form3.spot(onchange='this.form.submit()') }}
</form>
```

Comment: I am hopeful at this response--seems like what I may need. Will play with this now.

Comment: I get NoneType is not iterable in the first if statement where I assign choices for the second form.